# Modify values in a selector - Recoil

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I am fetching an API, destructuring it and storing values into individual selectors. I want to update a certain selector. I am able to do it using

```
  const connection = useRecoilValue(connectionState);
  const setConnection = useSetRecoilState(connectionState);
```

Is there an alternate to achieve this or this the best way?

This is my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-star-wc430?file=/src/Connection.jsx:167-280

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox no longer works (404 from azure). However, regarding the included code snippet, you could refactor it to one line.

`const [connection, setConnection] = useRecoilState(connectionState);`